# Why is string.find_first_of behaving this way?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a (assembly) parser which uses a string as a guide for how to cut the text to get the tokens I want.

```
string s = "$t4,";
string guide = "$!,$!,$!";
int i = 1;
string test =s.substr(0, s.find_first_of(" ,.\t"+to_string(guide[i+1]) ));
cout <<  test << "\n";
```

if s = "$t4" then test = "$t"

what I am expecting it to do is test to be "$t4", this works for every other $tX except for specifically the number 4 even though it's not in the (" ,.\t"+to_string(guide[i+1])) string

Comment: I fount out it's to_string(character) that is the source of the problem

Answer (score 2):

```
s.find_first_of(" ,.\t" + std::to_string(guide[i + 1]))
```

Assuming ASCII, that string will be:

```
 ,.\t44
```

44 is the ASCII value of the `,` in `guide[i + 1]`.
The first character in `"$t4,"` that it'll find is `4` at position `2`, and you then create a substring from `0` and length `2`, that is `$t`.

Comment: What is the most practical way to add a character variable to a string?
I fixed my program by doing `string temp = guide[i+1];`
then use `find_first_of(" ,.\t"+temp)`

Comment: @Different Sure, that works. You could also use a `std::string` literal. `using namespace std::string_literals;` and then `" ,.\t"s + guide[i + 1]` - note the `s` after `" ,.\t"`